# Is it possible to directly delete a file forever in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

I would like to directly "delete forever" a file in Google Drive. Is this possible?

In doing so, I want to avoid the extra step of deleting the file from the Trash can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, there is no way to delete something from Google Drive without it first going into the Trash and for you to delete it from there permanently.

There are plenty of people on the [Google Drive Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/drive) complaining about this.

Then again, it seems that there are nearly as many people complaining that they can't recover a file that they said to "delete permanently", so I suppose Google is splitting the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just a minor question: What in your opinion is the best channel to reach out to Google developers on matters like this?

Comment: @orschiro: I would use the "Feedback" tool that they've been building into their apps lately. After that, I'd post on the Google Product forums.

Comment: Thank you! I think I will apply the same method of feedback giving. However, it would be great if there was more feedback from there side, too.